# How to determinate intersection of two paths given start points(latitude and longitude) and bearings?

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, intersection

I have two points each one of them and its latitude, longitude and bearing (azimuth), and I need to check if the paths of each point intersect and the exact latitude and longitude of that intersection. I haven't found the formula for this type of problem. Does anybody know how to do this?
(I'm coding in c#)

Comment: that's solving a linear equatation system. you have to transform point and bearing in an equatation ax + by = c, so you got two equatations with two unkwons. on computers this would be solved easily with the determinant method

Comment: Just in case: b = 1, a= -(tangens(bearing)), compute c from point